# PHP, MySQL, IIS7.5 is taking far too long for simple queries

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7.5, performance

I've created a simple PHP test page which connects to a MySQL database, selects one int value, and then frees the result. The page takes 5 seconds or more to load. I've seen a lot of posts about this or similar issues but not of the resolutions have worked. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
mysql_connect took 4.8948628902435 seconds
mysql_select_db 0.00073790550231934 seconds
mysql_query took 0.0013959407806396 seconds
mysql_free_result took 2.0980834960938E-5 seconds
```

As you can see, the connection takes far too long and everything else is fast.

#### What I've tried

- Disabled IPv6
- Used IP instead of FQDN for the MySQL host.
- Tweaked some config settings.

#### The Facts

- All other non-PHP sites respond instantly.
- Pinging the MySQL server give 1ms latency.
- Querying the database using MySQL Query Browser gives instant response times.

FYI - I don't do PHP so it's okay to treat me like a baby when suggesting fixes.

#### The Test Script

```
<?php
    $mtime = microtime();
    $mtime = explode(' ', $mtime);
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
    $starttime = $mtime;

    mysql_connect("the_ip||the_hostname", "the_username", "the_password");

    $mtime = microtime();
    $mtime = explode(" ", $mtime);
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
    $endtime = $mtime;
    $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
    echo '<h2> mysql_connect took ' .$totaltime. ' seconds</h2>';
?>
```

Trace route is instantaneous:
By the way, the application in question is [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org/) as well as Wordpress.

```
  1     2 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  1.2.3.4
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  MYSQL5 [5.6.7.8]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another thing to look at is "mysql_connect" which might show you that PHP is having a hard time resolving (finding) the mysql host.  Are you using a IP address, localhost, or hostname? (when connecting to the database in php)  If it's a hostname try and add the IP to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host

if that doesn't work.
If all your "The Facts" are correct then you might have a issue with your php script.  Can you post it so I can see what you are running?  Also post the mysql table info like "Indexes" etc.

:)

Comment: In point 2 of "What I've Tried" I mention I've tried to use the IP. I'll post the (crappy) test script I'm using.

Comment: Richard's answer reminded me of another issue I had a while ago (with Apache and Ubuntu, but it might apply here). PHP, when it was sending a command to `sendMail`, was taking over 10 seconds to process that. I had to add the following to the etc/hosts file:

`    127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain my-computer-name`\n
`    173.203.87.144  my-computer-name`
Could it be a related issue? (etc/hosts is the host file for Linux http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: Nice @Charles!  Learned something new about the mysqli.  I haven't needed it yet but next project I will go in this direction.

Comment: Hey Josh.  i am not sure if your server is live or a production server.  But it might be worth trying something other than using IIS to control this.  Maybe try something like XAMPP which comes with all the required packages.  That's ofcourse if you don't have a linux box to try.

Comment: You and your Linux high-horse! ;-) Kidding, sort of. Actually this issue has been magically resolved. I'm going to chalk it up to a DNS issue. I'm thinking perhaps the reverse lookup from the MySQL server to the web server was slow or not working properly? Not sure. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI I accepted this answer because in the end it did turn out to be a DNS/IP/Network related issue.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the issue is back. My host has confirmed that it's not the MySQL server (tested the same script from a few other servers). It's also happening with a .NET 4 app that uses MySQL. I just switched my .NET test page to use v2 instead of v4 and I got instant responses (before it was 5+ seconds). Switching back to v4, I’m getting fast responses still. But the MySQL test page is still very slow. Very confusing! Specially since I have other .NET apps which are using MySQL and they are working fine (running on v2 of the .NET Framework).

Comment: Curious if you could do a trace route to the mysql host.  Start > Run > cmd > tracert YOUR_MYSQL_HOST.  Paste the results.

Comment: I added the output from tracert to the bottom of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, PHP was accessing MySQL with a simple select statement but taking for ages to display.

With help from another forum, the guy suggested that I make a new website and give it a different port than 80, so I did, In IIS manager, under sites, add new site and point it to the virtual DIR, entered the IP address of the server 192.168.2.2 and gave it port 82.

Opened port 82 in firewall and from a networked XP machine entered into the browser 192.168.2.2:82 and it was lightening. Worked first time.

Also, in the IIS manager for the new website, In Output Cacheing, Uncheck Use-mode cache, and it lets the pages run and enter data using the php pages.

A bit late with the reply, but thought I would share it any ways.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try these two test scripts as well?  (Note the `microtime` change -- the thing you're doing is an ancient PHP4 hack... *you aren't using PHP4, are you?*)

This one will test the MySQLi extension, if it's available:

```
<h1>MySQLi Test</h1>
<?php
    $starttime = microtime(true);

    $db = new mysqli("the_ip||the_hostname", "the_username", "the_password");

    $endtime = microtime(true);
    $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
    echo '<h2> mysqli_connect took ' .$totaltime. ' seconds</h2>';
```

And this one tests the PDO extension, if it's available:

```
<h1>PDO Test</h1>
<?php
    $starttime = microtime(true);

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=host_or_ip", "the_username", "the_password");

    $endtime = microtime(true);
    $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
    echo '<h2>PDO took ' .$totaltime. ' seconds</h2>';
```

If both of these experience the same delay, then we know it's not just something in the ancient "mysql" extension code.

Comment: Thanks for those - I added the original mysql_connect and ran all three and I get: [mysql_connect took 4.870668888092 seconds] [mysqli_connect took 4.8568620681763 seconds] [PDO took 4.9574251174927 seconds]

Comment: @Josh, this tells us something useful.  What version of PHP do you have installed, please?  And does it have a `php-cli.exe`?  Also, are you using the old and busted ISAPI DLL, or are you using FastCGI?

Comment: Hi, it is PHP 5.3 using FastCGI. (Copying from my comment posted on Richard's answer.) Actually this issue has been magically resolved. I'm going to chalk it up to a DNS issue. I'm thinking perhaps the reverse lookup from the MySQL server to the web server was slow or not working properly? Not sure. Anyway, thanks for your help!